# <?php echo $this->baseurl ?>

Tags: php, joomla

I don't know why but I'm trying to make this joomla template and the logo image it doesn't work, if you can see in the first code below (this is the code from the element inspector in the website) there is something weird with the link for the logo image, and in the second code below (the code in the index.php) there is "?php echo $..." I really don't know what is wrong, please help me, this is making me crazy.

**FIRST CODE**
*(this is the code from the element inspector in the website)*

```
<div class="logo">
                <img src="/joomla/ /joomla" alt="Logotipo">
                <h1>Localhost</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

**SECOND CODE**
*(the code in the index.php)*

```
<div class="logo">
                <img src" <?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
                <h1>Localhost</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try `<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">`

Comment: I did it and still not working

Comment: Please add `var_dump($this->baseurl, $this->template;):` to the index just before this div and put what it prints in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src"
```

Where is the `=` before the `"`

Also, `;` after `echo $this->baseurl`

Can you show us the code that `$this` refers to?

Comment: `<header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src=" <?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
                <h1>Localhost</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <nav class="mainmenu">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" style="xhtml" />.
            </nav>
        </header>`

Comment: I don't know what re u trying to tell me with "the code that $this refers to?" what code?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
<img src = "/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_FOLDER_NAME/img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">
```

Just make sure you and an img folder in your template directory and logo.png in that folder.  And replace the folder and in the path shown above for your template folder.

See here regarding possible issues with your JURI. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/where-is-this-baseurl-defined-in-joomla

Comment: That's really not good form though since it will break as soon as you make a copy of the template.

Comment: Well, since he already tried the correct syntax of:  <img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo"> Then this is probably the next best option.

Comment: Probably figuring out what is broken is the best option but you could certainly do that as a bandaid in an emergency.   For example maybe he need to have livesite defined.